# Can a form execute both an onSubmit and an action?

Tags: reactjs, forms, post, action, onsubmit

I'm building an app with a Form where I have an onSubmit that executes a javascript function I defined.

Now I want to submit the data to Salesforce Pardot (its a CRM).
To submit it to Pardot I have to define an action on the form.

My problem is that when submitting the Form the javascript onSubmit function executes, but the action does not.
And if I remove the onSubmit from my form, the action does in fact execute.

Is it possible to do both, execute a Javascript function onSubmit and send a post action?
Pardot (the salesforce thing) does not support ajax by the way.

Thanks!

Comment: does your onsubmit do `event.preventDefault()` or `return false`?

Comment: Hi Esther,
Neither of them. I'm using React. it sets a State to a certain value.